# How to pass data as XML via sockets?

Tags: c++, c, xml, sockets

I want to exchange data in the form of `XML schema` between socket programs written in C/C++. Could someone please provide links tutorials which describe the process of exchanging XML schema between socket programs.

I have two software tools running in different Operating Systems, in which I coupled with socket programs written in c/c++. As both work with `XML`, I want to know if there is a simple way to exchange data in the form of XML documents in order to run simulation studies.

Thanks in advance.

---

the question is how to send xml schema through a socket program written in C/C++ ?  here is an exp:

----- xml ---
...
`<xs:element name="zone">`
`<xs:complexType>`
`<xs:sequence>`
`<xs:element name="Var_name" type="xs:string"/>`
`<xs:element name="var_value" type="xs:decimal"/>`
`</xs:sequence>`
`</xs:complexType>`
`</xs:element>`

------ C/C++ ----
...
// send message to server
if (send(csocket, buffer_snd, BUFSIZE, 0) > BUFSIZE)
cout << send() failed << endl;
...

Thanking you in advance for your help,

Comment: Could you be more specific on the requirement? If all you want to do is to exchange XML encoded data, it is nothing more than sending a piece of text over the network using the popular Berkeley sockets API. There are many free tutorial on the web that shows you how to use it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. my question is not about sending just ASCII strings (or text as you said), but is how to exchange an xml document between client and server programs.

Comment: An XML document is an ASCII string. Just one with more angle brackets in it.

Comment: Yes! it is but it isn't what I am looking for? thanks!

Comment: @mk: In a comment, below, you indicate that you're trying to use gSOAP.  following the link posted, there's a tutorial with a bunch of links, and the documentation includes demos for both web services and XML.  Maybe you should update the question to indicate exactly what trouble you're having - what have you tried to do, and what doesn't work, or what part of the tutorial or docs don't make sense to you - instead of asking for resources you already have.

Comment: @atk: thanks for your reply. Yes, there is no diference between this question and the other one,. But I posted the other to make the question more clear ... thanks

Comment: @mk: if the questions are the same, may I suggest closing one of them?  Also, you can edit your questions - you don't have to repost.  In fact, reposting splinters the conversation, while editing your question would keep things easier to follow.

Comment: @atk: thanks! Sorry as I am new here, I don't know all rules. Actually,  I tried to close it but it doesn't because it contains answers ... thanks again for your reply

Comment: Please, share if you find a good method.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using an XML parsing library with a streaming parser for this, assuming you can rely on the documents being well-formed on both ends - well-formed XML is self-delimiting.  Something like [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) should be suitable.

Answer (score 2):

It seems what you want is to specify your protocol in XML Schema and then auto-generate C++ classes that would allow you to parse and serialize the XML messages. If so then you may want to take a look at [CodeSynthesis XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) which is an XML Schema to C++ compiler. It does pretty much exactly what you are looking for. If you want a more lighter-weight version, there is also XSD/e which is geared more towards mobile/embedded development.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) contains relevant code, not sure if that's what you're looking for, though.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how HTTP does this - simple header that indicates length of the payload that follows, plus some extras like timestamps and types. All you need to tell the other side is how many bytes to read from the socket and maybe the file name. You might also want to implement an acknowledgement back to the sender depending on your application needs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [expact library](http://expat.sourceforge.net/), this is a good xml parser, which can create xml object and can be send